# Cannot link MS Access query with subquery

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have created a query with a subquery in Access, and cannot link it in Excel 2003: when I use the menu `Data` -> `Import External Data` -> `Import Data...` and select the mdb file, the query is not present in the list. If I use the menu `Data` -> `Import External Data` -> `New Database Query...`, I can see my query in the list, but at the end of the import wizard I get this error:

```
Too few parameters. Expected 2.
```

My guess is that the query syntax is causing the problem, in fact the query contains a subquery. So, I'll try to describe the query goal and the resulting syntax.

**Table Positions**

- ID (Autonumber, Primary Key)
- position (double)
- currency_id (long) (references Currency.ID)
- portfolio (long)

**Table Currency**

- ID (Autonumber, Primary Key)
- code (text)

**Query Goal**

- Join the 2 tables
- Filter by portfolio = 1
- Filter by currency.code in ("A", "B")
- Group by currency and calculate the sum of the positions for each currency group an call the result: sumOfPositions
- Calculate abs(sumOfPositions) on each currency group
- Calculate the sum of the previous results as a single result

**Query**

The query without the final sum can be created using the Design View. The resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT Currency.code, Sum(Positions.position) AS SumOfposition
FROM [Currency] INNER JOIN Positions ON Currency.ID = Positions.currency_id
WHERE (((Positions.portfolio)=1))
GROUP BY Currency.code
HAVING (((Currency.code) In ("A","B")));
```

in order to calculate the final SUM I did the following (in the SQL View):

```
SELECT Sum(Abs([temp].[SumOfposition])) AS sumAbs
FROM [SELECT Currency.code, Sum(Positions.position) AS SumOfposition
FROM [Currency] INNER JOIN Positions ON Currency.ID = Positions.currency_id
WHERE (((Positions.portfolio)=1))
GROUP BY Currency.code
HAVING (((Currency.code) In ("A","B")))]. AS temp;
```

So, the question is: is there a better way for structuring the query in order to make the export work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problems thanks to the fact that the outer query is doing a trivial sum. When choosing `New Database Query...` in Excel, at the end of the process, after pressing `Finish`, an `Import Data` form pops up, asking

> Where do you want to put the data?

you can click on `Create a PivotTable report...` . If you define the PivotTable properly, Excel will display only the outer sum.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see too much wrong with it, but I would take out some of the junk Access puts in and scale down the query to this, hopefully this should run ok:

```
SELECT Sum(Abs(A.SumOfPosition)) As SumAbs
FROM (SELECT C.code, Sum(P.position) AS SumOfposition
      FROM Currency As C INNER JOIN Positions As P ON C.ID = P.currency_id
      WHERE P.portfolio=1
      GROUP BY C.code
      HAVING C.code In ("A","B")) As A
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did. Afterwards, Access did add the junk stuff. Anyway this query cannot be exported to excel.

Comment: I think I have to use the excel Pivot Table feature that takes the query result of the inner query and put them into a Pivot that takes care of the final sum.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying to declare your parameters in the MS Access query definition and define their datatypes.  This is especially important when you are trying to use the query outside of MS Access itself, since it can't auto-detect the parameter types.  This approach is sometimes hit or miss, but worth a shot.

```
PARAMETERS [[Positions].[portfolio]] Long, [[Currency].[code]] Text ( 255 );
SELECT Sum(Abs([temp].[SumOfposition])) AS sumAbs
FROM [SELECT Currency.code, Sum(Positions.position) AS SumOfposition
FROM [Currency] INNER JOIN Positions ON Currency.ID = Positions.currency_id
WHERE (((Positions.portfolio)=1))
GROUP BY Currency.code
HAVING (((Currency.code) In ("A","B")))]. AS temp;
```